# Creating terraform resource aws_key_pair error: InvalidKey.Format: Key is not in valid OpenSSH public key format

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I tried to generate the public key using the below command

```
ssh-keygen -f mykey
```

this created mykey and mykey.pub file in the respective directory

however, when I tried terraform apply to create a VPC I keep getting below error:

```
Error: Error import KeyPair: InvalidKey.Format: Key is not in valid OpenSSH public key format
    status code: 400, request id: 751910f2-4261-4c05-b296-f9bf5ea97ad1

  on keypairs.tf line 1, in resource "aws_key_pair" "mykeypair":
   1: resource "aws_key_pair" "mykeypair" {
```

The code is below

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "mykeypair" {
    key_name = "mykeypair"
  public_key = "${file("mykey.pub")}" 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the key to an openssh format using the `-f` flag. That should fix the issue as that's reported in the error message:

```
ssh-keygen -i -f mykey.pub > mykey-openssh.pub
```

[Amazon docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#how-to-generate-your-own-key-and-import-it-to-aws) also mention that pem formats are supported. You could also try supplying `-m PEM` parameter to create PEM keys.

You'll then have to use the openssh format in your resource:

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "mykeypair" {
    key_name = "mykeypair"
  public_key = "${file("mykey-openssh.pub")}" 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @pijemcolu. This worked for me now. ssh-keygen -i -f mykey